# Swift: transform image data into different valid image data

Tags: swift, uiimage, nsdata

I am trying to do something which I thought was simple, but turns out to be not quite so simple. I have a UIImage A, from which I can extract the NSData A. I can obviously turn back the NSData A into UIImage A. This is not an issue.

What I am trying to do is apply a transformation to NSData A to turn it into NSData B, from which I should be able to get a UIImage B, different from UIImage A. It doesn't matter what UIImage B is, as long as it is different from UIImage A, the point is to make image A unrecognizable. I should be able to get NSDAta A back from NSData B through a reverse transformation. So this is what should happen:

UIImage A -> NSData A -> Transformation function -> NSData B -> UIImage B

I have tried transforming the NSData A into a String, then altering the String and turning the altered String into NSData B (for instance by changing all occurrences a certain character into another one), but this outputs invalid NSData objects. Should I try at the byte level? I am not too familiar with this. How can I get the resulting NSData object to be valid to create a UIImage object from it?

EDIT: Added details on the type of transformation, and here is the code I have tried:

```
var image = UIImage(named: "image")
        print("IMAGE \(image)")
        var data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)
        print("DATA1 \(data)")
        var string = data?.base64EncodedString()
        print("String1 \(string)")
        var newString = self.crypt(string: string!)
        print("NEWSTRING \(newString)")
        var newData = NSData(base64Encoded: newString, options: NSData.Base64DecodingOptions.ignoreUnknownCharacters)
        print("NEWDATA \(newData)")
        var newImage = UIImage(data: newData as! Data)
        print("NEWIMAGE \(newImage)")

 func crypt(string:String) -> String {
        var cryptedString = string
        var range = cryptedString.startIndex..<cryptedString.index(cryptedString.startIndex, offsetBy: 10000)
        cryptedString = cryptedString.replacingOccurrences(of: "A", with: "b", options: .literal, range: range)
        return cryptedString
    }
```

I specified a range, because otherwise it will take too much time. This code seems to fail after newData (since it isn't nil), with this message:

```
 2016-09-22 03:06:42.548429 MessagesExtension[15720:3258392] [MessagesExtension] ImageIO: handle_error:349: IHDR: invalid
2016-09-22 03:06:42.548674 MessagesExtension[15720:3258392] [MessagesExtension] ImageIO: handle_error:349: IHDR: invalid
NEWIMAGE nil
```

Comment: Show your code what all you have tried so far. That would help us to debug your issue.

Comment: What transformation are you talking about? Resize, change contrast, convert to black and white, sepia tone, etc? `UIImage` encodes its data in a way that nobody but Apple knows so byte-level manipulation won't get you very far

Comment: The init function UIImage(data: `NSData`) return a UIImage? If may be the function to valid the `NSData`.

Comment: I have edited my question with more details.

Comment: Question, does the start and the end of `newData` and `data` are the same? Because, a PNG image has some Start/End of File that needs to be specific, and you don't seems to take that in account in `crypt(string:)`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#File_header

Comment: You are right, I am not taking it into account because I didn't know about this type of constraint. I was guessing there was probably something like that, but I don't know what. Do you know where I can find those constraints for NSData and UIImagePNGRepresenation? The documentation doesn't say too much about that.